# Hibernate collection not updated on child move

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm inherited a hibernate mapping and am having trouble moving a child node from one parent node to another. Either I get a duplicate reference, or I get an error.

I have locations in a tree. I want to move one leaf node to another leaf position. In code I'm trying to do this:

```
GeographicLocation oldParent = location.getParent();
location.setParent(newParent);
newParent.getChildren().add(location);
oldParent.getChildren().remove(location);
```

Causes:

```
org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException: deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations): [com.test.GeographicLocation#11]
```

If I remove the line `oldParent.getChildren().remove(location)`, the `newParent` node correctly points to the child, but the `oldParent` still has a reference to the child as well(!).

Snippets from hibernate config file:

```
<class name="GeographicLocation" table="GeographicLocation">
  <id column="GeographicLocationId" name="geographicLocationId" type="java.lang.Long">
    <generator class="native">
      <param name="sequence">GeographicLocationId</param>
    </generator>
  </id>

<many-to-one class="com.test.GeographicLocation"
   foreign-key="ParentFK" name="parent">
  <column name="parent"/>
</many-to-one>

<bag cascade="all,delete-orphan" inverse="true" lazy="false" name="children">
  <key column="parent" not-null="true"/>
  <one-to-many class="com.test.GeographicLocation"/>
</bag>
```

I haven't been using Hibernate very long. My understanding is that the `location` node, being a managed object, will save itself when modified. Since the hibernate config file specifies `cascade=all` changes to the collection will also save changes to the child. However, I can't seem to find a legal way to remove the old reference. Any help?

Comment: Seems a duplicate of:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649249/deleted-object-would-be-re-saved-by-cascade-remove-deleted-object-from-associat

Answer (score 1):

I would remove the `delete-orphan` from the mapping, since it says that as soon as you remove an element from the collection, it should be removed (which is clearly not what you want).