# org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException: deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations)

Tags: oracle, spring, hibernate, oracle10g, composite-primary-key

I have 3 tables in Oracle (10g).

- Zone
- Weight
- ZoneCharge

Where `ZoneCharge` has a composite primary key(zoneId, weightId) which references to primary keys of the `Zone` and the `Weight` tables.

I need to delete all the rows from the `ZoneCharge` table based on the `zoneId` supplied (the `weightIds` are unknown in this case).

The native Oracle SQL to achieve this would be as simple as follows.

```
DELETE FROM zone_charge WHERE zone_id=22;
```

---

I have tried the following way (in DAO).

```java
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Transactional(readOnly=false, propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void delete(Long id)
{
    Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    Zone  zone=(Zone) session.get(Zone.class, id);
    Set<ZoneCharge> zoneChargeSet = zone.getZoneChargeSet();
    int i=1;

    for(ZoneCharge zoneCharge:zoneChargeSet)
    {
        ZoneChargePK zoneChargePK=new ZoneChargePK();
        zoneChargePK.setZoneId(id);
        zoneChargePK.setWeightId(zoneCharge.getWeight().getWeightId());
        zoneCharge.setZoneChargePK(zoneChargePK);
        session.delete(zoneCharge);

        if(i++%50==0)
        {
            i=1;
            session.flush();
            session.clear();
        }
    }        
    session.getTransaction().commit(); //The exception is caused at this line.
    session.close();
}
```

It caused the following exception.

```java
org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException: deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations): [model.ZoneCharge#tempPackage.ZoneChargePK[zoneId=22, weightId=164]]
```

The stacktrace:

```java
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException: deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations): [model.ZoneCharge#tempPackage.ZoneChargePK[zoneId=22, weightId=164]]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:927)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doDelete(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:653)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:152)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter.doFilterInternal(MultipartFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at filter.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:144)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1822)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException: deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations): [model.ZoneCharge#tempPackage.ZoneChargePK[zoneId=22, weightId=164]]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.forceFlush(SessionImpl.java:1224)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:726)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:718)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingAction$5.cascade(CascadingAction.java:258)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:326)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:412)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:353)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:329)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.cascadeOnFlush(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.prepareEntityFlushes(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1212)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:400)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)
    at dao.ZoneChargeDAO.delete(ZoneChargeDAO.java:131)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at $Proxy928.delete(Unknown Source)
    at controller.ZoneCharge.delete(ZoneCharge.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:746)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:915)
    ... 70 more
```

---

In case, the associated entities are needed, they are as follows.

Zone:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "ZONE", catalog = "", schema = "WAGAFASHIONDB")
public class Zone  implements java.io.Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ZONE_ID", nullable = false, precision = 35, scale = 0)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "zoneIdSequence", sequenceName = "ZONE_SEQ", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "zoneIdSequence")
    private Long zoneId;
    @Column(name = "ZONE", length = 50)
    private String zone;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "zoneId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Country> countrySet;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "zone", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<ZoneCharge> zoneChargeSet;
    @JoinColumn(name = "TRANSPORTER_ID", referencedColumnName = "TRANSPORTER_ID")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Transporter transporterId;

    //Mutators and accessors
}
```

---

Weight:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "WEIGHT", catalog = "", schema = "WAGAFASHIONDB")
public class Weight  implements java.io.Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "WEIGHT_ID", nullable = false, precision = 35, scale = 0)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "weightIdSequence", sequenceName = "WEIGHT_SEQ", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "weightIdSequence")
    private Long weightId;
    @Column(name = "WEIGHT", precision = 35, scale = 2)
    private BigDecimal weight;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "weight", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<ZoneCharge> zoneChargeSet;

    //Mutators and accessors
}
```

---

ZoneCharge:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "ZONE_CHARGE", catalog = "", schema = "WAGAFASHIONDB")
public class ZoneCharge  implements java.io.Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EmbeddedId
    protected ZoneChargePK zoneChargePK;
    @Column(name = "CHARGE", precision = 35, scale = 2)
    private BigDecimal charge;
    @JoinColumn(name = "ZONE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ZONE_ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Zone zone;
    @JoinColumn(name = "WEIGHT_ID", referencedColumnName = "WEIGHT_ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Weight weight;

    //Mutators and accessors

}
```

---

ZoneChargePK:

```java
@Embeddable
public class ZoneChargePK  implements java.io.Serializable
{
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ZONE_ID", nullable = false)
    private Long zoneId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "WEIGHT_ID", nullable = false)
    private Long weightId;

    //Mutators and accessors
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere have to be an association to that object (List, Map, Set, etc...) you have to remove that Object from there first before you can delete it.

Simular question was asked here: [deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649249/deleted-object-would-be-re-saved-by-cascade-remove-deleted-object-from-associat)