# Hibernate: deleted object would be re-saved by cascade

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Definition:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, orphanRemoval = true)
@Where(clause = "ownerType=22")
private List<AirlineSupplierProductFile> files = new ArrayList<AirlineSupplierProductFile>(0);
```

The code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/remove-product-file", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = BaseController.AJAX_HEADER)
public @ResponseBody JSONResponse removeProductFile(@RequestParam(value = "id", required = true) Long id,
        @RequestParam(value = "product", required = true) Long productId,
        @CurrentUser UserDetailsExtended currentUser) {
    JSONResponse json = new JSONResponse();

    try {
        AirlineSupplierProductFile file = (AirlineSupplierProductFile) fileStorageService.get2(id, OwnerType.AirlinesSupplierProduct);
        if (file.getProduct() == null || file.getProduct().getId() == productId)
            fileStorageService.delete(file);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        json.setData(I18n.getString("errors.common.unexepected"));
        json.setCode(AjaxError.Undefined);

        log(e, currentUser.getUsername());
    }

    return json;
}
```

where `fileStorageService.delete(file)` is:

```
@Transactional
public void delete(IFileStorageFile object) {
    Session session = SessionFactoryUtils.getSession(sessionFactory, false);

    session.delete(object);
}
```

The problem: fails with `deleted object would be re-saved by cascade`.

The question: why??

Thank you

Comment: Will this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15820491/org-hibernate-objectdeletedexception-deleted-object-would-be-re-saved-by-cascad

Comment: @JtheRocker Nope. The problem as you can see that I don't any list to remove the object from... I populate the object from db and execute delete command.

Comment: this may be due to AirlineSupplierProductFile file still having the reference to the file object when you are calling delete(file). Try copying the file object to a different AirlineSupplierProductFile object and use that to delete from session.Something like delete(copied_file_obj);

Comment: @JtheRocker what do you mean "AirlineSupplierProductFile file still having the reference to the file object"? The AirlineSupplierProductFile IS the object

Comment: I mean copy the file object to a different instance of AirlineSupplierProductFile e.g. file2 and then use delete(file2).

Comment: @JtheRocker didn't helped.. the file has been restored again

Answer (score 0):

Remove the AirlineSupplierProductFile from the list of airlineSupplierProductFiles of its owning product:

```
AirlineSupplierProductFile file = (AirlineSupplierProductFile) fileStorageService.get2(id, OwnerType.AirlinesSupplierProduct);

if (file.getProduct() == null || file.getProduct().getId() == productId) {
    if (file.getProduct() != null) {
        file.getProduct().removeAirlineSupplierProductFile(file);
    } 
    fileStorageService.delete(file);
}
```

Comment: It is very strange, I have a lot of another entities with same relationships and everything fine during deletion.. Maybe it is possible to detach that entity manually befits calling 'delete'?