# deleted object would be re-saved by cascade when not deleting

Tags: hibernate

I've seen several answers to this but none of them are fixing my problem.

[org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException: deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18358407/org-hibernate-objectdeletedexception-deleted-object-would-be-re-saved-by-cascad)

[org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException: deleted object would be re-saved by cascade : Error while trying to delete a Patient object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45910335/org-hibernate-objectdeletedexception-deleted-object-would-be-re-saved-by-cascad)

I'm not even trying to delete, but I set a status to -1 and elsewhere in the app the object filtered on its status so that must be the delete.

I'm trying to set the user.status to -1

```
        user.setType(-1);
        userService.updateUser(user);
```

User has this in its class

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", updatable = false)
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
private List<UserGroupMembership> groupMemberships = new ArrayList<UserGroupMembership>();
```

This is in UserGroupMembership

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.JOIN)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
private UserPreview user;
```

Error is

```
deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations): [server.model.dao.entities.UserGroupMembership#22]; nested exception is
org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException: deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations):
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you show the operation you're trying to do that is causing this error?

Comment: yes thanks have added it

Comment: What happens when setType is -1? Does it just update the type column in the database to -1?

Comment: yes. Other things use that as a way to filter the membership, but nothing in UserGroup or UserGroupMembership. It's such a weird one!

Answer (score 0):

The entity I was updating had some missing attributes which was what was being deleted, I reconnected those by refetching the entity and it was fine.